# COUNTIFS in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a countifs formula that counts cancellation dates of clients by month, but the condition I want to also implement is not to count if the cancellation date was today's date (which is input in cell B1 at the top of the document).

So, for the november row, i have the formula `=ArrayFormula(countif(month(H4:H89),11))` which works to count every cancellation date that happened in the month of november, but I want to add a condition that says, "but don't count if date `=B1` enter code here where `B1` contains that day's date.

I've tried converting the conditions in the array formula to a countifs formula but it never seems to work. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(A2:A,"<>"&B2,MONTH(A2:A),11))
```

[image]